# 中身の入ったフォルダーを削除したい

Tags: linux, zsh

中身が入ったフォルダーを削除したかったので、

```
rmdir -p folder
```

試しましたが、"folder is not empty" と表示されます。
どうすれば削除できるでしょうか？

man を見ても -p オプションしか載ってません。

Comment: [rmdir](https://eng-entrance.com/linux-command-rmdir) と [rm](https://eng-entrance.com/linux_command_rm) の違いでは？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rmdir コマンドは空のディレクトリを削除するためのコマンドです。むしろディレクトリの下にファイルがあった場合削除しないのが正常動作で、そのような場合の誤削除を防ぐためのコマンドです。

再帰的にディレクトリの中身も削除したい場合は rm コマンドを使ってください。

```
rm -r folder
```